What is the motivation behind the Heisenberg Hamiltonian?
The magnetic interation between two fermions could be described by the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}=-J\hat{S}_1\hat{S}_2$, where $\hat{S}_1, \hat{S}_2$ are the spin operators. Where does this hamiltonian come from? Is there a classical analogy?

This belongs on History of Maths and Science but has a trivial answer. The rockstar Curie couple had already worked out quite a lot of the theory around magnetism via mean field approximation, and deduced that the experimentally observed magnetism is way too strong to be explained by known physics at the time. When spin-half became to be known, Heisenberg could then study that particular form of interaction. The actual size of $J$ comes from exchange interaction, i.e. Coulomb + symmetry, and thus has no classical analogy.

@naturallyInconsistent On the contrary, I think you've answered (in small detail) the question "Where does this hamiltonian come from?" or "What is the motivation behind the Heisenberg Hamiltonian?" This question strikes me as exactly asking the question about the physical origin of this model, not its historical origin, which you've answered! So consider writing an answer (unless you still deem it off-topic in some way, which is possible).

@naturallyInconsistent Nice fact about the Curies. I asked now a question Curie and „magnetism way to strong for known physics“ (at that time)

The Heisenberg Hamiltonian was developed as an effective model of ferromagnetism. By this I mean that it emulates the known behaviour of ferromagnetic materials without explaining the underlying causes.
In ferromagnetic materials, the magnetic moments (and therefore the spins) of neighbouring atoms tend to align. Aligning the magnetic moments normally costs energy  because of the dipole-dipole-interaction. Therefore, there must be something special going on in ferromagnetic materials that causes the aligned spins to have a lower energy than non-alignés spins.
As an effective model, we take the simplest form of a Hamiltonian that describes this behaviour. We simply introduce a constant $J$ by which we lower the energy if two neighbouring spins are aligned, and conversely increase it if they are antiparallel. The dot product in the Heisenberg Hamiltonian captures exactly this behaviour, plus intermediate values for configurations in-between these extremes.
As for your second question, the classical version of this model is usually simply called the classical Heisenberg Hamiltonian. It replaces the spins by vectors, everything else is the same. The origin of $J$ and this exchange interaction remains fundamentally quantum, but the Heisenberg model (both quantum and classical) don't care.

Great answer. To follow up why doesn’t this Hamiltonian have the units of energy?

@user408412 you're right of course that it should have dimensions of energy, and it does, if you use the spin quantum number operator (spin operator divided by $\hbar$) or simply set $\hbar = 1$.
